# post-processing of multi-column log file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, columns

I am working on post-processing of multi-column log filles, in the following format:

```
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_420,6, -5.3300, 201.2781, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.2132
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_420,5, -5.2300, 230.0910, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.2092
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_420,4, -5.1500, 222.2095, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.2060
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_420,5, -5.0500, 201.1757, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.2020
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_420,2, -5.0200, 233.0833, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.2008
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_420,5, -4.9500, 203.5671, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1980
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_420,4, -4.9500, 227.0462, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1980
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_420,14, -4.7700, 231.9237, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1908
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_03_lig_cne_420,5, -4.7200, 194.9009, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1888
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_420,3, -4.6700, 217.3995, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1868
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_420,1, -4.6400, 200.7227, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1856
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_420,1, -4.5900, 184.7898, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1836
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_420,3, -4.5500, 215.7487, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1820
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_420,3, -4.4500, 198.2857, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1780
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_07_lig_cne_420,1, -4.4200, 204.6418, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1768
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_420,6, -4.3700, 199.5359, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1748
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_06_lig_cne_420,6, -4.3500, 232.3248, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1740
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_06_lig_cne_420,3, -4.2700, 234.3468, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1708
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_420,1, -4.2500, 195.9439, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1700
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_03_lig_cne_420,7, -4.2400, 198.9363, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1696
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_03_lig_cne_420,1, -4.1600, 208.6377, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1664
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_01_lig_cne_420,3, -4.1500, 179.4341, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1660
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_12_lig_cne_420,4, -4.1300, 233.9607, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1652
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_420,1, -4.1200, 189.5660, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1648
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_420,1, -4.1100, 209.8679, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1644
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_420,5, -4.1000, 213.5573, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1640
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_08_lig_cne_420,1, -4.0700, 227.6124, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1628
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_420,3, -4.0400, 209.6345, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1616
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_06_lig_cne_420,4, -3.9700, 233.5914, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1588
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_420,4, -3.9500, 223.9189, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1580
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_05_lig_cne_420,1, -3.9000, 180.8133, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1560
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_11_lig_cne_420,1, -3.9000, 224.1828, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1560
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_02_lig_cne_420,1, -3.8800, 204.1735, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1552
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_09_lig_cne_420,1, -3.8500, 195.5399, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1540
/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_cne_lig420.AllBoxes/7000_10_lig_cne_420,2, -3.8400, 227.9037, 0,,  26,  8, 1, -0.1536
```

Note that the columns 1 and 2 separated by comma (,), while the rest column by comma space(, ).
From this log file I need to:

1. replace all data in the first column (long unix-format pathway `/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/...`) with the corresponding line number (just line N);
2. remove enterily columns 6-9 ( the four last columns);

Eventually the resulting log should contain the same number of rows but only from the column 1 (with substitution!) to 5 (the last column with `0,`).

What I have been able to accomplish is the substitution within the first column using sed, which however just cut the pathway but does not introduce corresponded line number there:

```
sed -i '' -e 's|\/Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/sub_folders_to_analyse/*.*/||' log.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gawk -F'^[^,]*,|, ' '{ print NR, $2, $3, $4, $5; }' OFS=', ' infile
```

to skip first *N* line(s), adds `NR> N` to the *awk*, so first *N* lines will be skipped; to skip first line, you would do:

```
gawk -F'^[^,]*,|, ' 'NR> 1{ print NR, $2, $3, $4, $5; }' OFS=', ' infile
```

Subsequently you will need to modify `NR` to `NR-1`, so it will start from *1* not *2*, or just replace it with another temp variable like:

```
gawk -F'^[^,]*,|, ' 'NR> 1{ print ++lineNumber, $2, $3, $4, $5; }' OFS=', ' infile
```

`^[^,]*,` matches from the beginning of the line up-to first comma character;
`,`   matches a comma-space characters.

these above we defined as filed separators (separated with `|`), and based on that we printed corresponding fields; `NR` in *awk* represents the current line number.

---

#### Another option is using `cut` and `nl`:

```
<infile cut -d',' -f2-6 |nl -w1 -s', '
```

`cut` command cuts the fields 2~6 and `nl` numbers the lines with comman-space separated `,` ; `-w` sets 1 width column to numbers.